# Post call not placing headers in call. Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to do an Api Call, this is the code I'm using

```
axios.get("url", userData, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "test"
        }
    }).then((response) => console.log(response, 'users/me'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Its showing me the same error everytime

401 (Unauthorized)

And on the network on chrome dev tools, the Authorization is not appearing at all

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It means probably you are not passing some tokens that you need your pass for api

Comment: It's a public API, and it's for one of my assignments, even on the swagger the API doesn't work, so maybe it's their problem.

Comment: Could you share it please in post then we can check

Comment: Its a private swagger, so i don't know if its right to share it, but thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization` reqest header has the following general scheme:

```
Authorization: <auth-scheme> <authorization-parameters>
```

Let us assume that your user id is `john.smith` and your password is `password` (don't do that).

Using the `Basic` authorization scheme, you take your user ID and password and join them with a colon:

```
john.smith:password
```

and then base-64 encyrpt that to get

```
am9obi5zbWl0aDpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

The `Authorization` header you need to pass then is

```
Authorization: Basic am9obi5zbWl0aDpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

Different schemes, of course, require different things in the header value.

Your `401 Unauthorized` response status *should* have a [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) response header containing a list of 1 or more *challenges* telling you what authentication scheme(s) you may use.

Install [Postman](https://www.postman.com) and fiddle with your API call until you get it working.

You can then export the API call as any of a number of different flavors of client-side code, `Node.js - Axios` being one of them.